# Using super() Multiple Times in a Python Class

Tags: python

Why does user.params() not return all the params up the inheritance
chain? -- It's not including the params defined in Person() -- notice
Vertex() does not have a params() method.

```
class Element(object):
   def __init__(self,element_type):
        self.oid = None
        self.uuid = uuid.uuid4()
        self.key = None
        self.element_type = element_type

   def params(self):
       return dict(uuid=self.uuid, key=self.key)

class Vertex(Element):
   def __init__(self):
       super(Vertex,self).__init__("vertex")

class Person(Vertex):

   def __init__(self,name=None,uri=None,email=None):
       self.s = super(Person,self)
       self.s.__init__()
       self.name=name
       self.uri=uri
       self.email = email

   def params(self):
       params = dict(name=self.name,uri=self.uri,email=self.email)
       params.update(self.s.params())
       return params

class User(Person):

   def __init__(self,
                name=None,
                uri=None,
                email=None,
                first_name=None,
                last_name=None,
                facebook_id=None,
                facebook_link=None,
                facebook_username=None,
                gender=None,
                locale=None):
       self.s = super(User,self)
       self.s.__init__(name,uri,email)

       self.first_name = first_name
       self.last_name = last_name
       self.facebook_id = facebook_id
       self.facebook_link = facebook_link
       self.facebook_username = facebook_username
       self.gender = gender
       self.locale = locale

   def params(self):
       params = dict(first_name=self.first_name,
                     last_name=self.last_name,
                     facebook_id=self.facebook_id,
                     facebook_link=self.facebook_link,
                     facebook_username=self.facebook_username,
                     gender=self.gender,
                     locale=self.locale)
       print self.s.params()
       params.update(self.s.params())
       return params
```

Comment: 1. That's not MI. 2. **What** are you trying to do in `Person.__init__()` and `User.__init__()`?

Comment: User's __init__ method calls Person's __init__ method via super() so that it has access to Person's methods and attributes. Person's __init__ method calls Vertex's __init__ method via super() in the same way.

Comment: No it doesn't. It puts a `super` proxy in an attribute and then calls a method on that.

Comment: What should I do instead? self.s is used again in params()

Comment: The same thing you did in `Vertex.__init__()`. Unless it doesn't make *sense* to do the same thing, in which case you quite seriously need to reconsider using inheritance there.

Comment: The goal is to call the parent's param() function in the body of the child's so that the child's param() returns all of the params from its ancestors.

Comment: You do know that using an attribute makes it *encapsulation* and **not** inheritance, right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**edit** : also the following code works, Sebastians has the correct interpretation: self.s is reassigned each time in the `__init__` of the classes. So `self.s` is reassigned as `super(Person,self)`.

```
import uuid

class Element(object):
   def __init__(self,element_type):
        self.oid = None
        self.uuid = uuid.uuid4()
        self.key = None
        self.element_type = element_type

   def params(self):
       print 'here Element'
       return dict(uuid=self.uuid, key=self.key)

class Vertex(Element):
   def __init__(self):
       super(Vertex,self).__init__("vertex")

class Person(Vertex):

   def __init__(self,name=None,uri=None,email=None):
       super(Person,self).__init__()
       self.name=name
       self.uri=uri
       self.email = email

   def params(self):
       print 'here Person'
       params = dict(name=self.name,uri=self.uri,email=self.email)
       params.update(super(Person,self).params())
       return params

class User(Person):

   def __init__(self,
                name=None,
                uri=None,
                email=None,
                first_name=None,
                last_name=None,
                facebook_id=None,
                facebook_link=None,
                facebook_username=None,
                gender=None,
                locale=None):
       super(User,self).__init__(name,uri,email)
       self.first_name = first_name
       self.last_name = last_name
       self.facebook_id = facebook_id
       self.facebook_link = facebook_link
       self.facebook_username = facebook_username
       self.gender = gender
       self.locale = locale

   def params(self):
       params = dict(first_name=self.first_name,
                     last_name=self.last_name,
                     facebook_id=self.facebook_id,
                     facebook_link=self.facebook_link,
                     facebook_username=self.facebook_username,
                     gender=self.gender,
                     locale=self.locale)
       print 'here User'
       params.update(super(User, self).params())
       return params

if __name__ == '__main__':
   u = User()
   print '\n'.join(sorted(u.params().keys()))
```

Answer (score 2):

In User you do:

```
self.s = super(User,self)
self.s.__init__(name,uri,email)
```

so self.s is what? As you do the same in Person, self.s is super(Person) and that anywhere, in Person and User as you reassign self.s, so the self.s.params that gets picked is the one of Element.